# Navbar (un)collapsed (un)hide header

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So, I am using bootstrap for my navbar. Thats all easy and simple and I have that implemented.

Since I have a header on top of my Navbar, I decided to put them both inside the same `row div` and give each a `col-md-12` so they would align. I then did

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {

    #titleRe {
        width: 75%;
    }

    #navRe {
        width: 25%;
        padding-top: 1.5rem;

    }

}
```

and it looks like this [navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mQjE.jpg) uncollapsed. As you can imagine, collapsed, it looks amazing and they are side to side, but when uncollapsed I can't view the navbar properly (for the obvious reasons).

My question is: How can I make the Header disappear when I open the navbar, and make the navbar centred?

Thanks

Comment: What is the Bootstrap version is used?

Comment: bootstrap-4. the latest it was on the website I believe. the folder is only called bootstrap-4

Comment: Keep in mind thats not a title, but a header.

Comment: You don't normally need (and shouldn't) touch css for manipulating simple things of this nature in Bootstrap 4. What you should do is post the code for the entire thing and not just a tiny snippet. Posting a screenshot is good but posting the code is even better!